# Wamp server and MySqlserver 5.5

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am new to MySQL and WAMP concepts. Now in client machine already MySQL is installed. Now i am trying to Install WAMP which is clashing. Without disturbing or touching, i would like to iinstall WAMP and use it. Can I do?

Comment: We don't know. Do you? Please be more specific.

Comment: Backup your databases in the existing MYSQL. Uninstall it. Install WampServer. Then restore the databases to the new wampserver MYSQL.